# MS SQL creating many-to-many relation with a junction table

Tags: sql, sql-server, many-to-many, junction-table

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and while creating a junction table should I create an ID column for the junction table, if so should I also make it the primary key and identity column? Or just keep 2 columns for the tables I'm joining in the many-to-many relation?

For example if this would be the many-to many tables:

```
MOVIE
Movie_ID
Name
etc...

CATEGORY
Category_ID
Name
etc...
```

Should I make the junction table:

```
MOVIE_CATEGORY_JUNCTION
Movie_ID
Category_ID
Movie_Category_Junction_ID
```

[and make the `Movie_Category_Junction_ID` my Primary Key and use it as the Identity Column] ?

Or:

```
MOVIE_CATEGORY_JUNCTION
Movie_ID
Category_ID
```

[and just leave it at that with no primary key or identity table] ?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I would use the second junction table:

```
MOVIE_CATEGORY_JUNCTION
Movie_ID
Category_ID
```

The primary key would be the combination of both columns.  You would also have a foreign key from each column to the `Movie` and `Category` table.

The junction table would look similar to this:

```
create table movie_category_junction
(
  movie_id int,
  category_id int,
  CONSTRAINT movie_cat_pk PRIMARY KEY (movie_id, category_id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_movie 
      FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movie (movie_id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_category 
      FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES category (category_id)
);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/002f1/2).

Using these two fields as the `PRIMARY KEY` will prevent duplicate movie/category combinations from being added to the table.

Comment: I would do the same thing.  Adding a third column makes it possible to have duplicate records.

Comment: is it necessary to create a composite primary key in this case?

Comment: @Harry.Naeem If you don't, then you could easily end up with duplicate records in the table. I wouldn't think you'd want that.

Comment: @bluefeet I have already created a table that has two foreign keys in it, should i just select them both and Set as Primary Key in sql server?

Comment: @Harry.Naeem Without knowing all the details, I'd just be guessing, so I suggest [you post a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide the details of your table structure, and possibly some sample data. You'd probably get a clearer answer from that, then by my guessing about your current setup.

Answer (score 23):

There are different schools of thought on this.  One school prefers including a primary key and naming the linking table something more significant than just the two tables it is linking.  The reasoning is that although the table may start out seeming like just a linking table, it may become its own table with significant data.

An example is a many-to-many between magazines and subscribers.  Really that link is a subscription with its own attributes, like expiration date, payment status, etc.

However, I think sometimes a linking table is just a linking table.  The many to many relationship with categories is a good example of this.

So in this case, a separate one field primary key is not necessary.  You could have a auto-assign key, which wouldn't hurt anything, and would make deleting specific records easier.  It might be good as a general practice, so if the table later develops into a significant table with its own significant data (as subscriptions) it will already have an auto-assign primary key.

You can put a unique index on the two fields to avoid duplicates.  This will even prevent duplicates if you have a separate auto-assign key.  You could use both fields as your primary key (which is also a unique index).

So, the one school of thought can stick with integer auto-assign primary keys, and avoids compound primary keys.  This is not the only way to do it, and maybe not the best, but it won't lead you wrong, into a problem where you really regret it.

But, for something like what you are doing, you will probably be fine with just the two fields.  I'd still recommend either making the two fields a compound primary key, or at least putting a unique index on the two fields.

Answer (score 4):

I would go with the 2nd junction table. But make those two fields as Primary key. That will restrict duplicate entries.